# How to manipulate double array data in C++?

Tags: c++

I am getting error C2297: '*' : illegal, right operand has type 'double *' in this piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double cx=0.5;
    double**image_array;
    image_array= new double*[5];
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        image_array[i]= new double[5];          
        for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            image_array[i][j]=0;
        }
    }

    for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            int i=cx*image_array[i,j];
        }
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone tell the reason. Can't I multiply the double array with double type data? Or what else can I do?

Comment: Instead of first `for` loop, use memset, if you really want to set everything to 0.

Comment: use a dedicated library, like Boost.MultiArray or Eigen depending on what you are doing.

Answer (score 4):

`image_array[i,j]` doesn't do what you want. You need `image_array[i][j]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few problems with your code - cleaning up the formatting, the main problem is your attempt to index image_array[i,j]. Use image_array[i][j] - here's a working interpretation of your code fragment, with some modifications.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{ 
    double cx=0.5; 
    double**image_array; 
    image_array= new double*[5]; 
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++) { 
        image_array[i]= new double[5];
        for(int j=0;j<5;j++) 
        { 
            image_array[i][j]=i*5+j; 
        } 
    }

    for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            double d=cx*image_array[i][j];
                        cout << d << "-";
        }
                cout << endl;
    }
    //system("PAUSE"); 
    return 0;
}
```

You can see sample output here: http://codepad.org/38r4CZ9W